# Are logical connectives allowed in the axiom schema of separation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The axiom schema of separation is $(\exists A)(\forall x)(x\in A\iff x\in B \land \varphi (x))$.

Patrick Suppes says the $\varphi (x)$ is a primitive formula. My question is if this is allowed to have sentential connectives such as "and", "or", etc.? for example could I say
$\varphi (x)= x\in C \land x\in D$?

Comment: Only $A$ must not occur in $\phi$

Comment: If I remember correctly having an $A$ in $\varphi (x)$ in a particular way can lead to Russell's paradox right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connectives and even quantifiers ($\forall$, $\exists$) are allowed inside $\varphi(x)$.